# Xcode Playground crashes with a simple UITableViewController code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swift-playground

I encountered a very strange problem with a `UITableViewController` subclass instance in the Xcode Playground.
I registered two `UITableViewCell`s programmatically in `viewDidLoad`, and dequeued cells in `cellForRowAt` method:

```swift
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UITableViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell1")
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell2")
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
      return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath)
    case 1:
      return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath)
    default:
      fatalError()
    }
  }
}

let vc = ViewController(style: .plain)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
```

But the Playground throws an `NSException` and shows:

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT.
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.
```

Note that this code works well in a legit Xcode Project with an iPhone simulator. Am I making a mistake here, or is it a bug?

I'm using Version 10.3 (10G8).

Comment: Check my edited answer...

Comment: Just a question, why would you set "cell1" and "cell2" as identifiers? They are both the same, i think its better to register only 1 cell with identifier "cell" and if you want to do more logics do that based on indexpath in cellforrow... But maybe i'm missing the point. Nevertheless, this is a strange "bug" (if its even a bug).

Comment: Setting `cell1` and `cell1` is not the point, as you mentioned :) It won’t work with custom TableViewCells, e.g., `class FooCell: UITableViewCell` and `class BarCell: UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curious bug...

This works fine:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell1")
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell2")
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath)
    }
}
```

But this crashes:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell1")
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell2")
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath)
    }
}
```

The ***only*** difference is that the example that crashes is returning the **second** registered cell.

If you swap the order of the `.register()` statements, then `"cell2"` works and `"cell1"` crashes.

---

**EDIT** *(Edit 2: we need to assign `.delegate` and `.dataSource` -- could be done in `loadView()` or `viewDidLoad()`)*

Note that, since registering (and using) only one cell works as-is, it *shouldn't* be necessary to set the view. However, if you do set the view in `loadView()` the code will run in Playground without crashing:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        let v = UITableView()
        v.delegate = self
        v.dataSource = self
        self.view = v
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell1")
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell2")
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath)
        case 1:
            return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath)
        default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried, and I can't see the set `textLabel`. Try `cell = tableView.dequeue...` and `cell.textLabel?.text = "..."`. It won't show on screen!

Comment: Hmm... strange, as I seem to recall doing some rather complex table view stuff in playground. However, yeah... Even with custom cell classes, I can only get it to work when registering only ONE cell.

Comment: @JayLee - whoops.... we need to assign `.delegate` and `.dataSource` ---- can be done inside `loadView()` or `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: Yeah.. But then what’s the point of using `UITableViewController` in the first place? Anyways, thank you for answer. I think I should report this issue to the bug tracker.

Comment: Yes, report it. UITableViewController contains this comment:

// Creates a table view with the correct dimensions and autoresizing, setting the datasource and delegate to self.

If the dataSource isn't set, there's a problem.